# Add preprocessor defines per config from a variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

How can you add a list of values from a variable to be in the preprocess in a config?

For example, I would like to have the preprocessor defines of "_TOOL" and "NO_AUTO_SAVE" but only when my config is Debug

I have tried several different attempts, the most promising seeming to be

```
set(RELEASE_ONLY_DEFINES "TOOL" "NO_AUTO_SAVE")
target_compile_definitions(MyProject PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${RELEASE_ONLY_DEFINES}")
```

However, I will have `$<0:TOOL;NO_AUTO_SAVE` set with the extra `$<0:` in my preprocessor define

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `cmake` syntax, but I can't help but notice that you have two opening angle brackets but only one closing one. That doesn't look right.

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure how I continued to miss that and how it generated that issue without an error. That resolved the issue